# List months ending on the same day of the week

Tags: bash, unix

This is an assignment. I have the following code:

```
#! /bin/bash

y=$1
if [ -z $1 ] # if year is not specified use the current year
    then y=(`date +%Y`)
fi

for m in {1..12}; do
    if [ $m -eq 12 ] # december exception
    then echo $(date -d $m/1/$y +%b) - $(date -d "$(($m%12+1))/1/$y" +%A)
          break 
    fi  
   echo $(date -d $m/1/$y +%b) - $(date -d "$(($m%12+1))/1/$y - 1 days" +%A) # print the last day of the week for the month
done
```

It lists the last day of the week for every month:

```
Jan - Monday
Feb - Monday
Mar - Thursday
Apr - Saturday
May - Tuesday
Jun - Thursday
Jul - Sunday
Aug - Wednesday
Sep - Friday
Oct - Monday
Nov - Wednesday
Dec - Saturday
```

Now I need to reverse it, so that it lists months ending on every day of the week like so:

```
Sunday - Jul
Monday - Jan Feb Oct
Tuesday - May
Wednesday - Aug Nov
Thursday - Mar Jun
Friday - Sep
Saturday - Apr Dec
```

I'm thinking of a nested loop,

```
for d in {1..7};
```

And storing months in an array?

Comment: Maybe this help with your question: `for i in {1..12}; do date -d "$i/1/2022 +1 month -1 day" "+%A %b"; done`

Comment: if all you need is a string/list of the months then consider an associative array where the index is the DOW and you append the 3 letter month on the end of the appropriate array entry (eg, last[Monday]="Jan Feb Oct"); to print in the desired order you could use a regular/numerically-indexed array to maintain the order of the DOWs (eg, dow[1]="Sunday")

Comment: I believe your "December exception" — default to the same day of week as January 1st of that year — fails on leap years.  Special handling December as simply `"12/31/$y"` would work, but the more general `+1 month -1 day` logic proposed by @Cyrus is better.

Comment: As the `bash` tag you used instructs, copy/paste your code into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# if year is not specified use the current year
declare -r year="${1:-$(date +%Y)}"

# associative array (aka hash table)
declare -A months_per_day=()
for m in {01..12}; do
    day_month=$(LANG=C date -d "${year}-${m}-01 +1 month -1 day" +"%A %b")
    months_per_day[${day_month% *}]+=" ${day_month#* }"
done

for day in Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday; do
    echo "${day} -${months_per_day[${day}]:-}"
done
```

Output:

```
Sunday - Jul
Monday - Jan Feb Oct
Tuesday - May
Wednesday - Aug Nov
Thursday - Mar Jun
Friday - Sep
Saturday - Apr Dec
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) your task can be solved:

```bash
INPUT='
Jan - Monday
Feb - Monday
Mar - Thursday
Apr - Saturday
May - Tuesday
Jun - Thursday
Jul - Sunday
Aug - Wednesday
Sep - Friday
Oct - Monday
Nov - Wednesday
Dec - Saturday
'

jq -Rrs '
  (split("\n") | map(split(" - "))) as $input |   # split lines and split each line by "-"
  reduce ("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday") as $day   # iterate over all weekdays
      ([]; . + [ ($input | map(select(.[1] == $day)) |        # select entries for $day
                 .[0][1] + " - " + (map(.[0]) | join(" ")))   # generate output for $day
               ]
      ) | .[]
' <<< "$INPUT"
```

**Output**

```
Sunday - Jul
Monday - Jan Feb Oct
Tuesday - May
Wednesday - Aug Nov
Thursday - Mar Jun
Friday - Sep
Saturday - Apr Dec
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer refactors your implementation as a reusable `getlastday` function. Then, we go through the loop 7 times matching the getlastday to the matching months, and print it out:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

getlastday() {
    if [ $m -eq 12 ]; then
        echo $(date -d "$(($m%12+1))/1/$y" +%A)
        return
    fi
    echo $(date -d "$(($m%12+1))/1/$y - 1 days" +%A) # print the last day of the week for the month
}

y=$1
if [ -z $1 ] # if year is not specified use the current year
    then y=(`date +%Y`)
fi

for d in Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday; do
    months=()
    for m in {1..12}; do
        lastday=$(getlastday)
        if [ $lastday != $d ]; then continue; fi
        months+=($(date -d $m/1/$y +%b))
    done
    echo $d - ${months[@]}
done
```

[EDIT: version 2]

As per @markp-fuso's comment below the above has an inefficiency in that there are 84 iterations to build the list.

The following is an improvement where we construct an `res` result array with 7 entries in it. One for each day in the week. Then we use `+%u` to get the day number instead of the day string. This will give us the index to the `res` result append where to append the month to:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

y=$1
if [ -z $1 ] # if year is not specified use the current year
    then y=(`date +%Y`)
fi

res=("Sunday    -" "Monday    -" "Tuesday   -" "Wednesday -" "Thursday  -" "Friday    -" "Saturday  -")
for m in {1..12}; do
    mstr=$(date -d $m/1/$y +%b)
    if [ $m -eq 12 ]; then
        d=$(date -d "$(($m%12+1))/1/$y" +%u)
    else
        d=$(date -d "$(($m%12+1))/1/$y - 1 days" +%u)
    fi
    res[$d]="${res[$d]} $mstr"
done
for d in {0..6}; do
    echo "${res[$d]}"
done
```

Comment: Because it is for an assignment, and, because code was already supplied, I wanted to offer an answer that was an incremental step from the answer provided. I am taking your feedback as constructive. Consider this as a version 1 with a known technical debt that can be refactored in version 2.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for time functions, with lots of intermediate and descriptively named variables to make it easy to understand:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v year="$1" '
    BEGIN {
        OFS = " - "

        year = (year == "" ? strftime("%Y") : year)
        secsInDay = 24*60*60

        for ( mthNr=1; mthNr<=12; mthNr++ ) {
            lastDayEpochSecs = mktime(year " " (mthNr+1) " 1 12 0 0") - secsInDay
            mthAbbrDayName = strftime("%b %A", lastDayEpochSecs)
            split(mthAbbrDayName,m)
            mthAbbr = m[1]
            dayName = m[2]
            mthNr2mthAbbr[mthNr] = mthAbbr
            mthAbbr2dayName[mthAbbr] = dayName
            dayName2mthAbbrs[dayName] = \
                (dayName in dayName2mthAbbrs ? dayName2mthAbbrs[dayName] " " : "" ) mthAbbr
        }

        for ( mthNr=1; mthNr<=12; mthNr++ ) {
            mthAbbr = mthNr2mthAbbr[mthNr]
            dayName = mthAbbr2dayName[mthAbbr]
            print mthAbbr, dayName
        }

        print "\n--------\n"

        for ( dayName in dayName2mthAbbrs ) {
            mthAbbrs = dayName2mthAbbrs[dayName]
            print dayName, mthAbbrs
        }
    }
'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
Jan - Monday
Feb - Monday
Mar - Thursday
Apr - Saturday
May - Tuesday
Jun - Thursday
Jul - Sunday
Aug - Wednesday
Sep - Friday
Oct - Monday
Nov - Wednesday
Dec - Saturday

--------

Tuesday - May
Friday - Sep
Sunday - Jul
Thursday - Mar Jun
Saturday - Apr Dec
Monday - Jan Feb Oct
Wednesday - Aug Nov
```

The above will be much faster than calling `date` multiple times in a shell loop and is trivial to modify to do anything else you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

year=${1-$(date +%Y)}

months=( Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec )
day_months=(    'Sunday    -'   'Monday    -'   'Tuesday   -'   'Wednesday -'
                'Thursday  -'   'Friday    -'   'Saturday  -'                )

for m in {1..12}; do
    last_day=$(date -d "$year-$m-1 +1 month -1 day" +%w)
    day_months[last_day]+=" ${months[m-1]}"
done

printf '%s\n' "${day_months[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare -A a
for i in '1/1 + 1 year' {2..12}/1; do
    d=($(LC_ALL=C date '+%A %B' -d "$i - 1 second"))
    a["$d"]+=${a["$d"]:+ }${d[1]}
done

for i in {Sun,Mon,Tues,Wednes,Thurs,Fri,Satur}day; do
    echo "$i - ${a["$i"]}"
done
```

This prints the list for the current year:

```
Sunday - July
Monday - January February October
Tuesday - May
Wednesday - August November
Thursday - March June
Friday - September
Saturday - December April
```

Answer (score 0):

technically the only info you'll need is what Jan ends on, and either (a) whether year is leap or not, or (b) whether Feb ends on same day of week as Jan.

The rest are easily deduced without running `date` 12 times

Answer (score 0):

Using `ksh93`:

```
#!/bin/ksh93

# if year is not specified use the current year
year="${1:-$(date +%Y)}"

typeset -A days

for month in Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
do
    lastday=$(printf "%(%A)T" "final day $month $year")
    days[$lastday]+=" $month"
done

for day in Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday
do
    printf "%-9s -%s\n" "$day" "${days[$day]:-}"
done
```

For 2022 produces the following output:

```
Sunday    - Jul
Monday    - Jan Feb Oct
Tuesday   - May
Wednesday - Aug Nov
Thursday  - Mar Jun
Friday    - Sep
Saturday  - Apr Dec
```

For 2023 produces the following output:

```
Sunday    - Apr Dec
Monday    - Jul
Tuesday   - Jan Feb Oct
Wednesday - May
Thursday  - Aug Nov
Friday    - Mar Jun
Saturday  - Sep
```